# Shell Scripting Case issue

Tags: shell

I am trying to make a shell script that takes arguments and then performs the appropriate mathematical equation depending on the second variable. I am receiving "syntax error near unexpected token `in" and "case "$y" in"

```
#!/bin/sh  
echo "Variable name \$1 $1"  
echo "Variable name \$2 $2"  
echo "Variable name \$3 $3"  
y=$2  
echo $y  
case $y in  
    '+')    x=`expr $1 + $3`  
            echo $x  
            ;;  
    '-')    x=`expr $1 - $3`
            echo $x  
            ;;  
    '\*')   x=`expr $1 \* $3`  
            echo $x  
            ;;  
    '/')    x=`expr $1 / $3`  
            echo $x  
            ;;  
    '%')    x=`expr $1 % $3`  
            echo $x  
            ;;  
    '*')    echo "Invalid option"  
            exit 1  
            ;;  
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Variable name \$1 $1"
echo "Variable name \$2 $2"
echo "Variable name \$3 $3"
y=$2
echo $y
case $y in
'+') x=`expr $1 + $3`; echo $x
;;
'-') x=`expr $1 - $3`; echo $x
;;
'\*') x=`expr $1 * $3`; echo $x
;;
'/') x=`expr $1 / $3`; echo $x
;;
'%') x=`expr $1 % $3`; echo $x
;;
*) echo "Invalid option"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

Some hints:
(1) '*' should be * at the end of case struct. * means all other case, while '*' means just *.
(2) x=expr $1 + $3 should be x=`expr $1 + $3`, ``(the backtick key) means to execute some command in sub shell and assign the output to x.
(3) to have multiple commands in one line, ';' should be used.
    x=`expr $1 % $3`; echo $x

Comment: I tried all of those changes and I am still receiving the same errors. It acts like its an error in the beginning of the case statement.

Comment: @Rurnel , I think you should check what shell is used. As your she bang is #!/bin/sh, type `ls -l \`which sh\`` and check the output. _Bash_, _dash_ and _sh_ should be acceptable results. [Here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-82) is a tutorial about case struct in shell. Just paste one example to your shell, and check whether there is something wrong. BTW, the full error output would help identify the problem.

Comment: 1rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2011-01-02 01:09 /usr/bin/sh -> /bin/bash

Comment: The problem is probably due to line ending character. Windows takes '\r\n', Linux takes '\n' and MAC OS takes '\r' as the end of line. Maybe you edit your file in Windows then upload it, or maybe you copy and paste the code from a webpage. Using `cat -v problem02.sh`(-v means to show nonprinting character) and check carefully at line 7, whether there is some output containing '^R' or  '^M'. If so, that's the problem.

Comment: @tianyapiaozi All of my line breaks contain ^M. I'm editing in Notepad++ and saving to my school server and connecting via Putty to run it on linux. Is this an issue of me editing on Windows or is this an issue of wrong encoding via Notepad++? Thank you for your help

Comment: @tianyapiaozi I got it fixed now I needed to encode the file in UTF-8 without Bom thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Rumel, glad to hear the good news. The root cause is Windows and Linux are using different EOL(end of line) character. Notepad++ has a menu to convert EOL character, i.e.,  `Edit`--->`EOL Conversion`---->`Convert to Windows,Unix,MAC Format`. If you convert your file to Unix EOL Conversion, the ANSI encoding will work, too.

Answer (score 0):

The last case clause should be

```
*)    echo "Invalid option"
```

i.e. remove not `'*'`

Comment: I've made all of those changes now but the problem still persists

Answer (score -1):

If you are using bash, change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`